# How to pass an array to a function instead of the values in it in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a function that takes in four doubles, and I have an array of four doubles. Is there any way I can just pass the array to the function? For example:

```
double[] myArray = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};

function myFunc(double val1, double val2, double, val3, double val4) {
    //do something with the values
}

myFunc(myArray[0], myArray[1], myArray[2], myArray[3]); // Do I have to do this?

myFunc(myArray); // Or can I do something like this?
```

Thank you!

EDIT: When I say `myFunc(myArray)` I mean "is there any format that Java has built in to allow me to do something that would be equal to this?" Sorry for not being clear about that :(

Comment: Did you try?  What happens?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Since my function doesn't take in an array, Java gets mad. I was wondering if there is some format or function/method I can use that is built in to Java to do this.

Comment: I suggest you read the array section in the standard Java tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: You need to change your method to accept an array, or create a new method that will do this.

Comment: `function myFunc` looks like javascript; the rest of your code looks like Java. So that's odd. In Java, `static void myFunc(double... args)` would allows you to declare a method that takes *variadic* arguments (e.g. like you say you want, or like the way you don't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `myFunc(myArray[0], myArray[1], myArray[2], myArray[3]); // Do I have to do this?`

No, but you'll wish you did.

Here's a simplified example for non-extended, boxed types using reflection. If you also want to support primitive types, you can add an override of `call` for each such type:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class Test extends ArrayCallable {
  void myFunc(Double val1, Double val2, Double val3, Double val4) {
    System.out.println("myFunc is running");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Double[] myArray = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
    new Test().call("myFunc", myArray);
  }
}

class ArrayCallable {
  void call(String name, Object[] params) throws Exception {
    Class[] types = Arrays.stream(params).map(c -> c.getClass()).toArray(Class[]::new);
    Method m = getClass().getDeclaredMethod(name, types);
    m.invoke(this, params);
  }
}
```

This is much slower and more error prone than your way, but it does sort-of allow you to do what you want.

> Why does Java make this difficult?

This is a conceptually problematic operation. You are trying to apply dynamic dispatch onto a statically typed language with static dispatch. The normal compiler and class load checks can no longer be relied upon. The system can't dispatch or JIT as efficiently, and the programmer has to deal with more typing errors at runtime.

Languages that do allow this easily (like Lisp or JavaScript) typically lack method overloading and passes arguments as lists anyways, and therefore don't suffer as much.

> What should I have done instead?

If you wanted to allow invoking `myFunc` with either a series of doubles or an array, you should have made it variadic.

This feels the same for the programmer invoking `myFunc`, but makes life easier by allowing Java to do static dispatch and allowing the implementor of `myFunc` to decide how to handle a variable number of arguments.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the parameter of your function to be:

```
function myFunc(double[] array) {
    //do something with the values
}
```

Now you will be able to pass the whole array to the function

```
myFunc(myArray);
```

Answer (score -2):

double[] myArray = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};

You can pass the object - myArray to your method, then read individual values stored in the array using an index:

```
public void someFunction(double[] myArray){
  double val1 = myArray[0];
  double val2 = myArray[1];    
}
```

and make sure you call the function in your main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    double[] myArray = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
    someFunction(myArray);  
}
```